# Spring kafka: how to disable kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I would like to disable the spring-kafka module in a specific profile, to ensure that we don't try to connect and interact with a Kafka that might not exist in a specific environnement ( on development machines as an example )

How can I achieve that? I already had a look at the [available properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html) and none seems to shut kafka off.

I would like something like:

```
spring.kafka.enabled: false
```

Comment: I would say this is more Spring Boot question, since Spring for Apache Kafka is just a library you add into your project. Yes, you can use `@Profile` on some `@Configuration` where you use `@EnableKafka`, but this is not available in Spring Boot and its auto-configuration. There is an `exclude` feature in Spring Boot, but you need to play a bit how to make it conditional: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using.auto-configuration.disabling-specific

Comment: I tried your suggestion; it indeed disables Kafka, but when I try enabling it with the profile it fails; "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'kafkaTemplate'". Is @EnableKafka the right annotation to re-enable it?

Comment: That is really expected if you exclude `KafkaAutoConfiguration`. Then you need to create `KafkaTemplate` bean yourself. Well, you may try to `@Import(KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)` on your profiled `@Configuration` though...